# facing Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')" error in python program

Tags: sql, excel, python-3.x, pyodbc

using python "pyodbc" module for extarcting data from excel sheet. When I use numeric instead of win_b64, This program works, for string i.e. win_b64 It is showing below error. I want to retrive data like in below condition 
"where platform = win_b64 and context_id = 806"

```
import pyodbc
exFile = r'C:\Python34\abc.xls'conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MicrosoftExcel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ='+exFile,autocommit=True)

curs1 = conn1.cursor()
excel = curs1.execute('select [problem_name] from [Sheet1$] where platform_name = win_b64 ;').fetchall()
p = (excel)
for x in p:
    print(x[0])
```

Error:

pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Have you tried `... where platform_name = 'win_b64'` ?

Comment: I tried but it's not working...:(

Comment: Same error? Different error? Any error at all? To simply say "not working" is not helpful.

Comment: 1st of all 'win_b64' syntax is not working in python query, I tried with "---" with this It also shows same error.

Comment: Thanks...for your effort...@Gord...!

Comment: Solution:

excel = curs1.execute('''select [problem_name] from [Sheet1$] where platform_name = 'win_b64' ;''').fetchall()

-> query syntax should be start in triple quot...and end too.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
excel = curs1.execute('''select [problem_name] from [Sheet1$] where platform_name = 'win_b64' ;''').fetchall()
```

-> query syntax should be start in triple quot...and end too.