# Why is this Python error code: Too Few parameters. Expected1. (-3010) occurring when using pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am writing a python script that executes some SQL code however whenever I call the function containing this SQL it gives me the error:

> File "Z:/ ... /Script.py", line 40, in Function
>
> cnxn.execute("""INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (007, Bond);""")
>
> Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

I have researched this problem and found other posts with the same error but I can't seem to apply the answers given to my code. For example:
[facing Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')" error in python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082907/facing-too-few-parameters-expected-1-3010-sqlexecdirectw-error-in-pyth)

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = (
        r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
        r'DBQ=Z:\ ... \DB.accdb;'
        )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
cnxn.execute("""INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (007, Bond);""")
```

I originally had only single quotes and tried what Navnath said in his answer and use triple quotes but that changed nothing. I believe that my SQL syntax is correct so I don't understand why this approach isn't working and why this error is coming up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're running the `.execute()` method from the connection rather than from the cursor you have opened. Also, it's always better to be explicit and use bound variables. Try this?

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = (
        r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
        r'DBQ=Z:\ ... \DB.accdb;'
        )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

crsr.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO Table1 (agent_number, agent_last_name) VALUES (?, ?)
    """,
    ('007', 'Bond')
)
```

Depending on your connection, you may also need to do a `.commit()` afterwards, since you're inserting, updating, or deleting data. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, pyodbc offers a [Connection.execute](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#execute) method as an extension to the DB-API, so doing `cnxn.execute("INSERT ...")` is actually valid code. Not the source of the problem, however (i.e., using `Bond` instead of `'Bond'`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this has helped me get past an incredibly infuriating problem!